# ObservableCollection event propagation and correct usage in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I am getting into MVVM and started out with the Prism framework and in my sample application I have typical navigation. One of the pages should list a few applications and I was wondering about differences in the implementation. To keep it simple here are some small snippets from the code thus far:

**Application Model**

```
public class Application : BindableBase
{
    private string _commandLine;
    private string _name;
    private string _smallIconSource;

    public string CommandLine
    {
        get { return _commandLine; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _commandLine, value); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }

    public string SmallIconSource
    {
        get { return _smallIconSource; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _smallIconSource, value); }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationPage ViewModel**

```
public class ApplicationPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Application> _applicationCollection;

    public ApplicationPageViewModel()
    {
        // load some collection entries here
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Application> ApplicationCollection
    {
        get { return _applicationCollection; }
        set
        {
            // if (_applicationCollection != null)
            //     _applicationCollection.CollectionChanged -= ApplicationCollectionChanged;
            SetProperty(ref _applicationCollection, value);
            // if (_applicationCollection != null)
            //     _applicationCollection.CollectionChanged += ApplicationCollectionChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationPage View**

```
<!-- ... -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- some kind of representation of applications -->
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<!-- ... -->
```

In some code samples on the internet, especially in some questions here on SO, I have seen people ask whether to store an `ObservableCollection` of ViewModels and not Models as I did - I was curious at this point when would you chose either of those version over the other one?

Furthermore I was interested in knowing whether changes in the `Application` class reflect in the `ApplicationPageViewModel` class or if I have to hook into the `CollectionChanged` event (as seen from Brian Lagunas' Webinars where I saw this technique). So far I have only seen this hook into the `CollectionChanged` event to call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method if `DelegateCommands` manually to prevent unnecesary bloat/calls when having the following implementation of `RelayCommand`s:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

Comment: Your question is basically how to inform items about that collection in which they are is changed. I could think of: 1) pass ViewModel instance to each item (constructor or whatever), item can subscribe to some event of ViewModel, event is rised by ViewModel (or even by item) 2) ViewModel handle all changes and notification (by calling each item method on collection change). Method (1) is given out the box if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (that's the event you will be listening to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ViewModels if the Properties in your Collection change. If the data on an item does not change it does not really make a difference if you use a VM or Model and is just how you prefer it.
I personally like to wrap my models in ViewModels, as i can easily add combined Properties for display, which i don't want to have directly in my models.

If you want to do some action on the ApplicationPageViewModel when an Application changes, you have to

- Use a ViewModel for Application
- Hook up the INotifyPropertyChanged event of each Application ViewModel
- Everytime you add a new Application, also add the Listener to this Application

If you just want to do some actions when an Application is added or removed, you don't have to use a ViewModel and just register the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection

Comment: Alright this clears up some things. Still I am wondering if you use ViewModels to include some combined properties you are definitely relying on the Facade pattern, aren't you? Doesn't this approch make maintainability more complex and force you to write duplicate code for access on same properties you dont want to hide?

Comment: For my current project, im using a DynamicObject wrapper for ViewModels where i just want to add some properties or view-dependend functionality. Thats not the fastest way, but very convinient, as i don't have to duplicate code for the properties, but just assign the Model for the ViewModel.

For my models i have no way to register to changes, as it does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but only holds the data.

Comment: Besides INotifyPropetryChanged sometimes it's necessary to add PropertyChanged => OnCollectionChanged if you have ObvservableCollections within ObservableCollections. I tried to automate it but never mind, it's easy and straightforwad enough to implement it manually.